# Bundler::GemNotFound when compiling assets from cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm deploying to servers with capistrano and doing a  bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile as the last step. Problem is when it gets to this point FROM cap deploy, i get the following error:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find Platform-0.4.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Platform-0.4.0 IS in fact on the server. And when i go into the server and run this exact command, all works great.

Couple of facts about my server: its using RVM, but that doesn't seem to be an issue with cap as the stack trace above would suggest. The other fact of interest is that this server was first created with a custom script I wrote that downloads an archived version of the git repo and then manually runs what cap does on a deploy. The reason I'm doing this, if anyone asks, is for automation with AWS AutoScaling. If i do a normal deploy:setup (not using my AWS script), it works fine with deployments. But the gem list is the same, and the site works all the same either way. Its just something with the cap deploy

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. on my custom AMI scripts, i was naming the initial release folder 'first' when it should be a timestamp the way capistrano normally names it. That screwed things up on subsequent deployments.